Sections of bundles induced by cocycles
Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold and let $ \{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A} $ be an open cover of $ M $.
Cocycles of transition functions on $ M $
A cocycle of functions on $ M $ with respect to the open cover $ \{U_\alpha\} $ is a family $ \{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A} $ of smooth maps
$$
\psi_{\beta\alpha}\colon U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb R^k)
$$
where $ \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb R^k) $ is the groups of all the linear automorphisms of $ \mathbb R^k $ such that
$$
\begin{align}
\psi_{\alpha\alpha}(p) &= \mathrm{id}_k\\
\psi_{\gamma\alpha}(p) &= \psi_{\gamma\beta}(p)\circ \psi_{\beta\alpha}(p)
\end{align}
$$
whenever all of this makes sense.
My question
Consider the vector bundle $ \mathrm{VB}(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}) $ induced on $ M $ by a cocycle of functions $ \{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\} $. Here $ \mathrm{VB}(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}) $ is obtained by identifying in the disjoint union $ \coprod_{\alpha\in A}(U_\alpha\times \mathbb R^k) $ elements that differ by a transition function (i.e. $ (x\in U_\alpha,v) $ and $ (y\in U_\beta,w) $ are equal in $ \mathrm{VB}(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}) $ if and only if $ x = y $ in $ U_\alpha\cap U_\beta $ and $ \beta = \psi_{\beta\alpha}(x)v $).
What is a section of $ \mathrm{VB}(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}) $? I mean,it should be a smooth map $ s\colon U\subset M\to \mathrm{VB}(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}) $ such that for every $ p\in U $ then $ s(x) $ is an element of the fiber of $ \mathrm{VB}(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}) $ at $ p $.
But how does this fiber looks concretely?
I mean, the fiber "is" $ \mathbb R^k $, of course, but not in a canonical way.
A concrete example
Let's look for example at how densities on $ M $ are defined. Given some atlas $ \{(U_\alpha,u_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in A} $ on $ M $, one defines the cocycle
$$
\psi_{\beta\alpha}(p) = \left\lvert\det\bigl(\mathrm d(u_{\beta\alpha})_{u_\alpha(p)}\bigr)\right\rvert\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\cong \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb R^1)\text{,}\qquad p\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta
$$
where
$$
u_{\beta\alpha} = u_\beta\circ u_\alpha^{-1}\colon u_\alpha(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)\to u_\beta(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)\qquad \mathrm d(u_{\beta\alpha})_{u_\alpha(p)}\in \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb R^{\dim M})
$$
are respectively the change-of-chart function and its differential.
A density on $ M $ is then a section of the vector bundle $ \mathrm{Vol}(M) = \mathrm{VB}(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}) $.
But what is a density concretely?

It's a family of local sections $U_\alpha \to U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k$ that are compatible with the gluing/transition maps. As for how the fibre looks, I don't know what description you're looking for. It's just $\mathbb{R}^k$, and over each $U_\alpha$ you have a canonical choice of trivialization by definition; it's just that if it also belongs to $U_\beta$, then the canonical local trivializations differ by an automorphism of the fibre. Perhaps working out the case of the Moebius bundle over $S^1$ might give some intuition.

You can try to draw yourself a smooth nowhere-vanishing twisted volume form (an n-density) on a physical Möbius strip. This is a mind-wrecking exercise, but very interesting, because non-orientability+twistedness won't allow you to draw a single volume at any point. One way I found a while ago was to draw simultaneously a pair of opposite volumes at each point, one per orientation of a basis. Then in a local chart, the coordinate representation of the volume is that one from the pair that matches the chart orientation. When you inspect it carefully, this plays also nicely...

...at the 2 chart intersections -- the orientation-preserving transition keeps the volume the same, the orientation-switching one gives the opposite choice of volume from the pair. But still the initial picture stays invariant and makes you imagine (in one possible way) how a twisted form may look like at a given point. IMO this also gives a nice sense of what other types of bundles may look like, though harder to visualise for bundles that are not (twisted) forms. If you think this helps but struggle to visualize it, I can try sharing a picture.

I would really like to (say) get some intuition about the Riemannian volume density on the Möbius strip but my problem is that I don't know how to handle this object (I mean, should I see it embedded in Euclidean space? Should I see it as a quotient with it's strange atlas? But how do I put a metric on this quotient?).  @Al.G. Yeah a picture will definitely be helpful!

After a little bit of thinking I had actually found a satisfying answer, but at the time I forgot to update this question. I'll leave my ramblings here just for reference.
Let's consider the vector bundle $ \mathrm{VB}\bigl(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}\bigr) $ that has for cocycle of transition functions exactly the cocycle $ \{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\} $. There's a bijection between the set $ \Gamma(M,\mathrm{VB}\bigl(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}\bigr)) $ of global sections of $ \mathrm{VB}\bigl(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}\bigr) $ and the set of all the families $ \{s_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A} $ of smooth mappings $ s_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to \mathbb R^k $ that "transforms as sections of $ \mathrm{VB}\bigl(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}\bigr) $", i.e., such that
$$
s_\beta(p) = \psi_{\beta\alpha}(p)\circ s_\alpha(p)
$$
for every $ p\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta $.
Given such a family $ \{s_\alpha\} $ one can show that the local sections $ \tilde s_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to \mathrm{VB}\bigl(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}\bigr) $ defined by
$$
\tilde s(p) = \psi_\alpha^{-1}(p,s_\alpha(p))\text{,}
$$
where $ \psi_\alpha\colon {\mathrm{VB}\bigl(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}\bigr)}|{U_\alpha}\to U_\alpha\times \mathbb R^k $ is the standard local trivialization, glue together to a section $ s $ of $ \mathrm{VB}\bigl(\{\psi_{\beta\alpha}\}\bigr) $.

Yes! I learned this from Gunning's Lectures on Riemann surfaces.
